# scroll not working while pressing navigation up/down button in cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: html, css, angular, keyboard-events, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport in my mat-autocomplete. scroll works fine whenever scroll using mouse but not working whenever pressing keydown button.

Expected Behavior:
If the focus goes beyond the visible viewport, the list should automaticly scroll down/up

Actual Behavior :
It just doesn't scroll, and if the end of the actuall renderd items is reached, it comes back to the start and doesn't render new items.

like in this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rmvpq

Comment: Hi @venkatesh, i'm facing the same issue, did you find the solution, any update?

Comment: Hi, still the same issue. Any solution?